# Record access for limited time

Tags: security

How would I automatically provide access to a Person Account record for only 15 minutes, if the user answered a security question correctly and then have it automatically revoked?

Scenario:

Customer calls in, the agent answers the call, the customer provides customer name, date of birth and postcode, entering these details into Salesforce provides the agent with access to the customer record for 15 minutes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do this without code, and even then, you'd need to think carefully about it. If you actually grant access to the record (via a Record Share), then if your code sets up a timeout fifteen minutes in the future, and it fails to revoke access, the user might be left with access indefinitely.

It seems to me the easiest way to enforce this would be to have a Visualforce page that uses "without sharing" in the controller to query the record despite the user not having access. At this point, you can then write code to "revoke" access to the record when the time expires or when the user leaves the page. At that point, it's simply a matter of writing up all the logic you need to display/edit the record's data.

Answer (score -1):

Why do you want to limit access like that? If you trust your users so little that you want to turn off access after 15 minutes, then it may be more of a systemic/HR problem than something that can be solved with technology.

Maybe you want to purchase Event Monitoring so you can see which users access which records, and so you can use Transaction Security to perhaps build something more robust to alert you.

Comment: Perhaps the data is very sensitive...

Comment: Giving a user access to that data for 15 minutes somehow gets around that? No.